# Why does Serialization process require access to a no argument constructor of the first non serializable super class?

Tags: java, serialization

From the [Serialization documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#4539)

> A Serializable class must do the following:
>
> 1. Implement the java.io.Serializable interface.
> 2. Identify the fields that should be serializable (Use the serialPersistentFields member to explicitly declare them serializable or use the transient keyword to deno nonserializable fields.)
> 3. Have access to the no-arg constructor of its first nonserializable superclass.

What is the premise behind the third point above?

Comment: See http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=251942

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the premise behind the third point above?

So that the non-Serializable base classes can be initialized to a known state that can be controlled to some extent by the programmer. It's just a design decision.

Comment: But how are those non-serializable classes getting initialized to a known state? Who is doing the work here?

Comment: Also can you please explain the *that can be controlled to some extent by the programmer* part of your answer. A code snippet in your answer would be helpful.

Comment: @Geek *The default no-args constructor of the nearest non-Serializable base class* is doing that. The one you are asking about. The programmer can 'control it to some extent' if he can put code inside it. Surely this is obvious?

Comment: But you wrote in a comment to upog's answer that "The default constructor doesn't 'initialize instance variables to their default value'. You can replace it by writing an empty constructor with arguments, and get the same effect"..is the difference here between known state and default state?

Comment: The point *here* is (a) that there must *be* a default no-args constructor for Serialization to call, and (b) that you can explicitly write your own no-args constructor and have it do anything you like.